# Input format support for linkage between objects

Tags: rigging, import

I'm attempting to render a 3D view of a network (actually exported as VRML from the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) graph drawing package) in Blender and would like the vertices and edges of the network to be physically connected (i.e. so that moving a vertex moves all edges connected to it, and vice versa).

Note that (as per the following diagram), unlike vertices and edges in a mesh, the vertices and edges in the network are compound objects.

[image]

Do any of the input formats that Blender supports allow such physical connections to be specified?